# Laravel Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $method ]] in class GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request

Tags: formularios, laravel-8

Estoy haciendo un logout pero cuando el usuario intenta cerrar sesión sale un error que dice:

> Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [  $method ]] in class GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request"

Mi formulario esta dentro de una lista en un *header* este es el código del form:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="{{ route('perfil') }}">Perfil</a></li>
    <li>
        <form action="{{ route('logOut') }}" method="POST">
            @csrf
            @method('put')
            <a href="#" onclick="this.closest('form').submit()">Cerrar Sesion</a>
        </form>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Este es el código de la ruta:

```
Route::put('logOut',[logInController::class,'logOut'])->name('logOut');
```

Y este es el código del *LougOut*:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Helpers\UDGOnline;
use App\Http\Requests\FormIngreso;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\User;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class logInController extends Controller
{
    public function authenticate(FormRequest $request)
    {
        $credentials = [
            'key' => $request->Codigo,
            'password' => $request->NIP
        ];
 
        if (UDGOnline::auth($credentials)) {
            $user = User::where('key', $credentials['key'])->first();
            if ($user == null) {
                $user = UDGOnline::createUser($credentials);
                UDGOnline::storeClasses($user);
            }
            if (Auth::loginUsingId($user->id, $request->recordar == 'on' ? true : false)) {
                $request->session()->regenerate();
                return redirect()->route('main');
            }
        }
 
        } 
        return back()->withErrors([
            'key' => 'Codigo y/o NIP incorrecto',
            'password' => 'Codigo y/o NIP incorrecto'
        ]);
    }

    public function logOut(Request $request)
    {
        Auth::logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();

        $request->session()->regenerateToken();

        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

¿Cómo puedo corregir el error y el usuario pueda cerrar Sesión?

Answer (score 1):

Para solucionar el error cambiar esta línea:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;
```

Y usa esto:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Espero te funcione.